# Value of tensor operation does not update after depending variable updated/assigned in tensorflow 2.2, running in eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I run the following code in tensorflow 2.2

```
a = tf.constant([2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
b = tf.Variable([4.0, 3.0, 5.0])
c = a * b
```

Value of `b` is:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([4., 3., 5.], dtype=float32)>
```

Value of `c` is:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 8.,  9., 20.], dtype=float32)>
```

if I update the variable b now

```
b.assign( [ 1.0, 1.0 , 1.0] )
# b is now <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>
```

But when i print the value of `c`, which i expect it should have changed since `b` has changed, but `c` does not change

```
# c is still <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 8.,  9., 20.], dtype=float32)>
```

My test is running in eager mode. tf.executing_eagerly() = True now

What is the reason behind?

Answer (score 0):

c has been attributed by the former b, if you want to change c, it needs to re-execute c=a*b